# AspectJ for Android activity

Tags: android, aspectj

I am using AspectJ for monitoring method flow for my Android activity. My Activity just has `onCreate`, `setContentView` and `startActivity`.

And my AspectJ for checking method flow is

`pointcut logGetTitleById() : execution (* Main.*(..));`

When I try to launch my activity on my phone, there is force close. I just suspect AspectJ has problems in executing inbuilt methods of Android. Is it true? Or how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Here is a wonderful blog that explains this http://ikrk.wz.cz/archiv/23-how-to-use-aspectj-with-android. It works :)